# Prove random vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ has non-degenerate distribution iff $\Sigma$ is positive definite

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X$ denote a $d$-dimensional random vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ satisfying $|\Sigma| < \infty$. 
Prove $X$ has non-degenerate distribution iff $\Sigma$ is positive definite.

Attempt at proof: Let $X$ have a non-degenerate distribution. Then $$\mathrm{Pr}(a_1 X_1 + a_2 X_2+\cdots+a_n X_n=c) \neq 1.$$

From here I'm not sure how to proceed. However, I believe it has something to do with a property of the variance of the covariance matrix $x$; specifically the fact that $\mathrm{Var} (a^T X) = a^T \Sigma a$ ($a \in \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Please replace `\sum` by `\Sigma`.

Answer (score 3):

$\Sigma$ positive definite $\iff$ there is no $a\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $a^T \Sigma a=0$ apart from $a=0$ $\iff$ there is no non-trivial linear combination $a_1 X_1 + \cdots a_n X_n$ with zero variance, according to your statement. Can you see how to proceed?

Comment: So the final part is just simply stating that due to these properties, the random vector X with covariance matrix $\sum$ must have a non-degenerate distribution?

Comment: @Ishihara You need to rigorously link zero variance with non-degeneracy, but yes.